# Регистрация и выдача token

Tags: php, get, token

Здравствуйте, у меня есть сервер на php.
Я со своего андроид приложение обращаюсь к страничке и получаю данные в формате json. Этот json может попасть в руки любого человека, например если узнать адрес на который отправляеся get-запрос.

Мне посоветовали сделать авторизацию в приложении с выдачей токена.

Не могу найти информацию по данной теме.
С чего начать?

Скиньте пару статей пожалуйста,спасибо.

Comment: android ту не при чем вообще.

Comment: @metalurgus согласен

Comment: Как вы внутри приложения определяете пользователей, которым можно скачивать данные?

Comment: @Sergiks в приложении все нормально, суть в том , чтобы не могли получить этот json в чистом видел(который выдает сервер)

Comment: Юзеры авторизуются как-то, или у всех скачавших оно в одинаковом состоянии?

Answer (score 1):

Тут все не сложно.

1) У каждого приложения есть guid.

2) Вы делаете авторизацию в своем приложении (например, по email+password) и фиксируете в базе авторизацию для этого приложения (guid), генерируя произвольный токен (любой ключ, чаще строковый), например md5 из email+time().

3) Обращаясь к закрытым частям своего апи вы передаете guid+token, а ваше приложение проверяет, если токен для этого guid существует (и не закрыт, т.к. вы можете поставить ему срок жизни, либо закрывать при logout пользователя из приложения), тогда выдавать ответ, а если закрыт, то отправлять на авторизацию.

Это очень общий механизм, просто чтобы объяснить схему работы. На деле кто-то усложняет, кто-то что-то меняет, кто-то оставляет как есть. Например, вместо того, чтобы писать свою авторизацию, можно перепилить oauth . Хотя, свою написать, не представляет особых сложностей ;)